# Add Commiters/Authors to NetBeans 11.0 Bitbucket Commits

Tags: java, git, bitbucket, git-commit, netbeans-11

I am developing some software in college and me and my partner are spliting the work and he sends me the code in raw and I commit it, but I want to commit his code in my NetBeans 11.0 on his name but i can only commit on mine and i want to be able to do it. Is it possible?

I already added 2 [user] camps to .git/config file in the repository but only i appear on the commit section on NetBeans CSV camp.

Here is a quick image of what I am referring to:

[image: Please click here to see the screenshot]

Comment: Why are you using this mode instead of both working with the git directly? That's what git is for.

Comment: I Am sorry I did not understan what you said. My partner is not used to git bash and hit interfaces and he asks me to do the commits. Plus he works on random computer because he doesn't run a laptop ao he makes the code on  the go...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal [NetBeans "Git commit" dialog](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#committing) does have Author and Committer drop-down lists, that allow to differentiate between those who made the change and who physically committed the file if necessary.

[image: NetBeans Git commit]

As shown by [bug 239587](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=239587), you should be able to *type* directly the `username <email@com>` of the author (even though you can keep your default Git config `user.name/email` for the committer field)

Comment: Yes, but how do I add another commiter to that drop down list?

Comment: @RafaelMoreira Once you have done a commit with his name at least once, the drop-box list should include said name.